# Casting XElement to int? fails when xsi:nil = "true" is specified

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

The XElement has explicit support for casting to Nullable<int> but it's not working as I expected.  The following unit test demonstrates the problem:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CastingNullableInt()
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<root xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><okay>123</okay><boom xsi:nil=\"true\"/></root>");
        Assert.AreEqual(123, (int?)xdoc.Root.Element("okay"));
        Assert.IsNull((int?)xdoc.Root.Element("boom"));
    }
```

The test should pass the last assert. Instead it gives an `FormatException`:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Why doesn't it parse to `null` correctly here?

Comment: define "not working as expected"

Comment: I expect the unit test to pass.  How can I possibly make that clearer?

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for improving my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XElement` does not parse `<boom xsi:nil=\"true\"/>` correctly. It only works if you omit `<boom xsi:nil=\"true\"/>`, then the value is `null` and it returns `(int?)null`.

A workaround could be to first check on the value not being empty:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)xdoc.Root.Element("boom"))
    ? (int?)xdoc.Root.Element("boom")
    : null
    ;
```

Comment: I was afraid this was the case but I wanted to toss it out there to see if I was missing something obvious.  Thanks Patrick!

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with this one. I hope the workaround is sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to XML is not schema aware so it will not convert `xsi:nil = "true"` to a nullable variable. To test this you would need to do something like:

```
Assert.IsTrue((bool?)xdoc.Root.Element("boom").Attribute("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil") == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
var value = xdoc.Root.Element("boom").IsEmpty ? null : (int?)xdoc.Root.Element("boom");
```